# Display a Button after X minutes of playing time of a Youtube Video?

Tags: javascript, api, video, youtube, embed

I want to show a simple Button after a youtube video has played for a few minutes. The User shouldn't be able to klick the button before he's seen some of the video.

I embedded the video simply like this:

```
<iframe id="video" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use html5 video API, you can add an eventListener for the 'play' event of the video. You can use this event to start a timer that will activate the button after some time. Alternatively, if you can't use video API, maybe a onload listener on the iframe will do the trick as well.

Comment: I made a little JSFiddle out of other code i found that looked pretty close to what i need. Could you take a look at it and tell me whats missing? https://jsfiddle.net/dLw7qfdm/1/

Comment: Add `setTimeout(enableButtons, 5000)` to function`onPlayerReady` (The one that starts playing the video.) This will call the `enableButtons` function after 5000 miliseconds. Then add some code to that function that will render your button. As a sidenote, might be smart to also pause the timeout if your user would pause the video before `enableButtons` is called. You can probably hook that into the stateChange function.

Comment: That's it! Thanks man ;-) And good idea with the pause-function. I'll try to do that!